# Is there a way to call Google Keyczar from node.js?

Tags: node.js, security, cryptography, keyczar

I need to generate some HMACs server side in my application written in node.js. Node does provide HMAC functionality in its crypto class:

http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac

However, keyczar has a few more features on top of this, particularly key rotation and management. Has anyone found a way to use keyczar from node.js, or perhaps implemented a key rollover strategy on top of node.js crypto?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me building a version of Keyczar on top of node.js's crypto would be pretty ideal, but, I don't know of anyone who has done it.

However, c++ keyczar also supports [swig](http://www.swig.org/) bindings. I think you might be able to find some work out there to make swig accessible from node.js, on Swig's homepage they mention a recent SoC project to that effect.

**Update:**

You could also use [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) to use the [C# version of keyczar](http://jbtule.github.io/keyczar-dotnet/) directly.

**Update2:**

[KeyczarJS](https://github.com/mitro-co/keyczarjs) can be found on github.